# Bad Packet Number error with libdrizzle (mysql) & gearman

Tags: mysql, gearman, libdrizzle

When I try to use libdrizzle/mysql with gearman, I get this error during startup:

DEBUG [  main ] libdrizzle replay: def -> libgearman-server/plugins/queue/drizzle/queue.cc:562 
ERROR [  main ] drizzle_row_buffer:drizzle_state_packet_read:bad packet number:4:110 -> libgearman-server/plugins/queue/drizzle/queue.cc:552

Tried with gearman 0.24 and 0.23. Also with libdrizzle7-release from the dev-drizzle repo, as well as the 8.23 and 8.25 from source.

Same error whether or not the database table is empty or has data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug fix submitted yesterday: https://bugs.launchpad.net/drizzle/+bug/528410